# Getting index of the current element in custom comparator function for `std::upper_bound`

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to use [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) to find the upper bound of an element inside `std::vector<double> xpositions`. The index of each element in `xpositions` needs to be used to index a multidimensional array. I tried

```cpp
upper_bound(xpositions.cbegin(), xpositions.cend(), value,
            [](const double& element, const double& value){
                // get index of current element
                const auto index = std::distance(xpositions.cbegin(), &element);
                // look up multidimensional array
                bigarray[index];
            }));
```

but this does not compile since `&element` cannot be converted to an iterator. Is there a way of getting the index of `element` without doing a potentially expensive `std::find`?

Comment: How do you know which of the references `value` or `element` refer to an element in the `vector`? I think your comparator is ill-defined.

Comment: I had them backwards by mistake. I will edit the post.

Comment: There is no requirement that the algorithm invokes your comparator with a particular order of the arguments. In fact, the debug version of the Visual C++ library will invoke both orders to verify that your comparator does not violate strict weak order. Your approach is doomed. If you need the index for your comparisons, your have to provide it explicitly in some other way. You can't derive it from the arguments.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound): "The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type1`. The type `Type2` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type2`."

Doesn't this imply that the first argument is the third argument to `upper_bound` and the second argument is the dereferenced value?

Comment: Interesting! Looks like you have a point here and I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in vector are stored in contiguous area, simple pointers arithmetic will do the job:

```
const auto index = &element - &xpositions[0];
```

also you need to capture `xpositions` by reference in your lambda.

If you want to use `distance` you have to pass non-const iterators of vector to `upper_bound`, and predicate should take non-const reference to double:

```
upper_bound(xpositions.begin(), xpositions.end(), value,
            [&](const double& value, double& element){
                // get index of current element
                auto index = std::distance(&xpositions[0],&element);
```

Comment: Doesn't the first snippet just calculate the address difference in bytes? We don't need to divide by the size of `double`? Also I didn't know `std::distance` accepts raw pointers. It doesn't show up as one of the [possible overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: *If the pointer P points to the ith element of an array, and the pointer Q points at the jth element of the same array, the expression P-Q has the value i-j, if the value fits in std::ptrdiff_t. Both operands must point to the elements of the same array (or one past the end), otherwise the behavior is undefined. If the result does not fit in std::ptrdiff_t, the behavior is undefined.* [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) it gives you the number of items between two pointers.